# At what speed does the magnetic field move from pole to pole?

Tags: electromagnetism

the magnetic field moves in a loop right? How long does it take to go from one pole to another?

Comment: if you think of the earth magnetic field, it does NOT move, the same for the magnetic field of a permanent magnet, or a coil.  or what did you mean?

Comment: in the diagrams of a magnet they show a looped direction arrow, at what speed do those arrows move?

Comment: Magnetic field lines only exist as closed loops.  There is no beginning and no end.  And those arrows in drawings are just to indicate the polarity of the field lines ... they don't move either.

Comment: @DavidWhite, isn't that an answer instead of a comment? Please see David Z's answer here:  [Do you find that answers in comments are a problem?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/966/9887)

Comment: @AlfredCentauri, I hesitated to post my comment as an answer because I thought that it didn't actually answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

> the magnetic field moves in a loop right?

Consider the *static* magnetic field due to a bar magnet. Is the magnetic field *moving*?

Sure, the diagrams that you see *suggest* that there is movement because there's an arrow on the field lines, right?

[image]

[Image credit](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/elemag.html)

But the arrows aren't an indication of movement, they're more of an indication of the direction of the magnetic field vectors that are tangent to the field line.

A magnetic field can, however, 'move' in the sense that it changes with time. For example, the magnetic field due to a current loop where the current is changing with time.

Answer (score 1):

The arrows on the field lines just show the direction of the field. A magnetostatic field like this just sits there, with a certain magnitude and a certain direction at each point. It’s not changing and not “moving”. It’s not like flowing water.

For example, the looping magnetic field of a point dipole $\vec m$ is

$$\vec B=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{3\hat{r}(\vec{m}\cdot\hat{r})-\vec{m}}{r^3}.$$

This expression is a particular vector at each point, and doesn’t represent a changing field.

Answer (score -2):

Magnetic and electric Fields carry the information of presence of a charge and are limited by the speed limit of the universe.

*They travel at the speed of light* This is still only experimentally verified. and theory on why speed is $c$ is not yet ready. There are developments going on - Quantum Electro Dynamics explains this by saying that two electrons exchange a virtual photon to feel the repulsion. And since magnetic fields arise is due to moving charges, $\vec B$ also travels at the speed of light.

Comment: Rishab, I've downvoted your answer because, on my view, the statements that you make aren't quite correct. They're not entirely wrong but they miss the mark regardless.

Comment: For example: *"They [magnetic and electric fields] travel at the speed light"*. But magnetic and electric fields don't travel at all. An electromagnetic *wave* (a propagating 'disturbance' *in* the electromagnetic field) 'travels' (propagates) with speed $c$ (in vacuum).

Comment: Another example: *"There are developments going on - Quantum Electro Dynamics ..."* Is QED an ongoing development? Does virtual particle exchange explain propagation at speed $c$? How?

Comment: the exchange particle for electrostatic attractions is a photon, which travels at the speed of light... So the exchange of information and propagation of force occur at the speed of light. Now $\vec E$ is just a scaled force and thus, it also propogates at speed $c$

Comment: Sorry for tge confusion : I called all attempts to explain the speed of $\vec E$ as "ongoing developments". We cannot call QED as an explanation to the phenomena. It hypothesises a particle exchange. A theory that explains the speed of force should be like General theory of relativity, where the speed of gravity is predicted as a result and not as an assumption